# How could I implement this Enum from Rust in Golang?

Tags: go, struct, enums, interface

I'm learning Go and I need to implement an equivalent Enum feature similar to this [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html)  (example in Rust, copied bellow). I'm struggling to implment the same functionality in Go. I know I could use `const` with `iota`, but the Enum type I need, like in the example, has mixed property types and some of them have an input argument.

Rust Example from [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html)

```
// Create an `enum` to classify a web event. Note how both
// names and type information together specify the variant:
// `PageLoad != PageUnload` and `KeyPress(char) != Paste(String)`.
// Each is different and independent.
enum WebEvent {
    // An `enum` variant may either be `unit-like`,
    PageLoad,
    PageUnload,
    // like tuple structs,
    KeyPress(char),
    Paste(String),
    // or c-like structures.
    Click { x: i64, y: i64 },
}

// A function which takes a `WebEvent` enum as an argument and
// returns nothing.
fn inspect(event: WebEvent) {
    match event {
        WebEvent::PageLoad => println!("page loaded"),
        WebEvent::PageUnload => println!("page unloaded"),
        // Destructure `c` from inside the `enum` variant.
        WebEvent::KeyPress(c) => println!("pressed '{}'.", c),
        WebEvent::Paste(s) => println!("pasted \"{}\".", s),
        // Destructure `Click` into `x` and `y`.
        WebEvent::Click { x, y } => {
            println!("clicked at x={}, y={}.", x, y);
        },
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pressed = WebEvent::KeyPress('x');
    // `to_owned()` creates an owned `String` from a string slice.
    let pasted  = WebEvent::Paste("my text".to_owned());
    let click   = WebEvent::Click { x: 20, y: 80 };
    let load    = WebEvent::PageLoad;
    let unload  = WebEvent::PageUnload;

    inspect(pressed);
    inspect(pasted);
    inspect(click);
    inspect(load);
    inspect(unload);
}
```

I created a `struct` for each Enum field that embeds a `WebEvent` interface, like so:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type PageStatus int

const (
    PAGELOAD PageStatus = iota
    PAGEUNLOAD
)

type WebEvent interface{}

type PageLoad struct {
    WebEvent
    status PageStatus
}
type PageUnload struct {
    WebEvent
    status PageStatus
}

type KeyPress struct {
    WebEvent
    key string
}

type Paste struct {
    WebEvent
    text string
}

type Click struct {
    WebEvent
    x, y int
}

func inspect(event WebEvent) {
    switch event.(type) {

    case PageLoad:
        fmt.Println("page loaded")

    case PageUnload:
        fmt.Println("page unloaded")

    case KeyPress:
        fmt.Println("pressed %v", event.key)

    case Paste:
        fmt.Println("pasted: %v", event.text)

    case Click:
        fmt.Println("clicked at x: %v, y:%v", event.x, event.y)

    default:
        fmt.Println("Event not recognized")
    }
}
func main() {
    pressed := KeyPress{key: "x"}
    pasted := Paste{text: "my text"}
    click := Click{x: 20, y: 80}
    load := PageLoad{status: PAGELOAD}
    unload := PageUnload{status: PAGEUNLOAD}

    inspect(pressed)
    inspect(pasted)
    inspect(click)
    inspect(load)
    inspect(unload)
}
```

but I'm getting a compilor error:  undefined (type WebEvent has no field or method key). I tried to cast the event to the struct type: `(KeyPress)(event)`, then I get other error:  cannot convert event (variable of type WebEvent) to type KeyPress: need type assertion.
Is this the best way to implement this Enum in Go? If so, how could I solve the error?

Comment: `switch event := event.(type) {` will fix the compiler error.

Comment: And in place of a [type conversion](https://go.dev/tour/basics/13) (`KeyPress(event)`), you would have needed a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) (`event.(KeyPress)`). But in the [type switch](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16), the previous comment's suggestion is better.

Comment: @mkopriva that does solve the error, thanks. Why do I need to reassign the event? I've seen some examples that don't need to do that, use just switch event.(type)... Regarding the implementation itself, you think there is a better way to implement that? I find my version a little lengthy, also I wish I could use the dot notation, like `pressed := WebEvent.KeyPress{key: "x"}`

Comment: @dgwk first you need to keep in mind that Go is a statically typed language, this means that it is **not possible** to change a variable's type at runtime. The `switch event.(type) {` version just checks the _dynamic type_ stored inside the interface, however, since you cannot change a variable's type, inside the `case T:` blocks the `event` remains of type `WebEvent`. With `switch event := event.(type) {` however, you are declaring a __new variable__ and the type of this new variable is determined based on the type in the `case T:` clause.

Comment: @dgwk perhaps it will be less confusing if you use a different name for the switch variable, e.g. `switch e := event.(type) {` and then you'd use `e.key` / `e.text` inside the `case` blocks.

Comment: @dgwk if you want to use dot notation you can move the event types to their own package, e.g. `<your_module_path>/webevent`, then have the `main` package import the `webevent` package and then you'll be able to do `webevent.KeyPress{Key: "x"}`. Note that I've changed `key` to `Key` to implicitly __export__ the identifier, this is because unexported identifiers (those that start with lowercase or underscore) are not accessible from outside of the package in which they were declared. Note also that I've used `webevent` instead of `WebEvent`, this is because MixEdCaSe package names are bad style.